# JavaScript Start over iterating when in the end

Tags: javascript

I'm completely stuck here. Here's the problem I'm solving:

> A shift cipher takes a plain text message and shifts each letter forward in the alphabet by a given number. For example, a shift cipher with a shift of 1 would turn the string 'hello' to 'ifmmp'.

Example:

```
const cipher = new ShiftCipher(2);
cipher.encrypt('I love to code!'); // returns 'K NQXG VQ EQFG!'
cipher.decrypt('K <3 OA RWRRA'); // returns 'i <3 my puppy'
```

Here's my code:

```
// Write class below
class ShiftCipher {
  constructor(num) {
    this.num = num;
  }

  encrypt(str) {
    const lowCase = str.toLowerCase();
    const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    let encrypted = '';

    for(let i = 0; i < lowCase.length; i++) {
       if(!alphabet.includes(lowCase[i])) {
          encrypted += lowCase[i];
        }
      
      for(let j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
        if(lowCase[i] == alphabet[j]) {
          encrypted += alphabet[j + this.num].toUpperCase();
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(encrypted);
  }
}

const cipher = new ShiftCipher(2);
cipher.encrypt('I love to codez!');
```

Last two lines is for testing my method. Everything works fine until iteration doesn't come to an end of alphabet. I added z to the end to test it working with last letter of alphabet. It should start over from alphabet so when I call Z with 2 it should return B but of course I get error because string ends and I'm unable to make it start over.

I've googled around and understand that `continue` might be solution here but I have still failed to use it in my code.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be this line:

```js
encrypted += alphabet[j + this.num].toUpperCase();
```

When you reach the end of the alphabet, the letter `z`, `j + this.num` will be greater than the length of the alphabet. Indexing the array out of range will produce `undefined` so your code breaks.

Add a wrap-around like this:

```js
encrypted += alphabet[(j + this.num) % alphabet.length].toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Wow it was this easy. I actually tried this but I didn't put `j + this.num` in parentheses and still got stuck. I was so close. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yeah, the `%` operator is higher precedence than `+`, so without the parentheses it'd be like `j + (this.num % alphabet.length)` which would make no sense - it'd still be possible to overflow